# "Uniform groups" (similar to topological groups)?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, uniform-spaces

Why have I heard about topological groups, but nothing about "uniform groups" (uniform spaces endowed with a group)?

Comment: If a topological group has a neighborhood $\mathcal{O}$ of $g$, is it not sufficient to translate that neighborhood to (say) $h$ by multiplying by $hg^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A topological group is a uniform space in two ways... one by left translation, the other by right translation.  Replace $x\cdot y^{-1}$ in Owen's answer by $y^{-1}\cdot x$ to switch.  The two are equivalent in abelian groups, compact groups, and in many others.  But not all.

I have heard it said that the notion of "uniform space" was originally given as a common generalization of "metric space" and "topological group".

Answer (score 7):

Every topological group is automatically a uniform group. In particular $G$ becomes a uniform space if we define a subset $V$ of $G\times G$ to be an entourage if and only if it contains the set $\{ (x, y) : x⋅y^{−1} \in U \}$ for some neighborhood $U$ of the identity element of $G.$

The way to think about it is that uniform spaces have ways to compare neighborhoods at different points, and the group action on itself allows us to do that for $G$.